# How to create all combinations of a list without using itertools or listtools?

Tags: python-3.x

so I'm working on creating a code which returns all combinations of sublists within a list as a nested list.  This can only be done using recursion and for/in loops.

For example,

```
allCombos([1, 2, 3])
```

would return

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
def allCombos(alist, a=0, b=1):
  newList = []
  if b < len(alist) + 1:
    newList += [alist[a:b]] + [allCombos(alist, a, b+1)]
  elif b == len(alist):
    a = a+1
    b = a+1
    newList += [allCombos(alist[a:len(alist)])]
  else:
    return newList
```

This only returns None.  What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have a look at the [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) entry for an example of how to write an equivalent function in python.  The just run it for each `r` in `range(len(iterable)+1)`

Comment: Based on the restrictions of the assignment, itertools and listtools cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 'None' because you wrote `newList+=` instead of `newList.append()`, using a plus sign doesn't add to an array.

Comment: Based on the constraints of the assignment I can't use append.  Is there a way to write that a different way?